# PHP MVC way to load helpers/model/views

Tags: php, model-view-controller

**Controller.php**

```
<?php    
class Controller {
    public function loadHelper($name) {
        require(APP_DIR . 'helpers/' . strtolower($name) . '.php');
        $helper = new $name;
        return $helper;
    }
}
```

**my_helper.php**

```
<?php
class My_helper {
    function do_something($value) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

**Main.php**

```
<?php
class Main extends Controller {
    function index() {
        $url = $this->loadHelper('my_helper');
        $url->do_something('value');
    }
}
```

### Question:

What approach should I use, if I want to load helper and use it like this:

```
$this->load->helper('my_helper');
$this->my_helper->do_something('value');
```

Thank you for your suggestions/tips/code in advance.

Comment: No reason to down vote, I am asking what APPROACH should I use. Not assuming that I am in correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the helpers I want to load in a property of the controller. When rendering the view I would pass the list of helpers to the View and the view should automatically load them when needed. Lookup [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

I don't think the Controller should do the loading of helpers because they belong to the View.   So the view should have a method like loadHelper(). Also I would recommend you to use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).